# Replace with multiple patterns mutually exclusively

Tags: ruby, regex, string, text

I have the following text:

```
a phrase whith length one, which is "uno"
```

Using the following dictionary,

```
1) phrase --- frase
2) a phrase --- una frase
3) one --- uno
4) uno --- one
```

I'm trying to replace the occurrences of the dictionary items in the text. The desired output is:

```
[a phrase|una frase] whith length [one|uno], which is "[uno|one]"
```

I've done this:

```
text = %(a phrase whith length one, which is "uno")
dictionary.each do |original, translation|
  text.gsub! original, "[#{original}|#{translation}]"
end
```

This snippet outputs the following for each dictionary word:

```
1) a [phrase|frase] whith length one, which is "uno"
2) a [phrase|frase] whith length one, which is "uno"
3) a [phrase|frase] whith length [one|uno], which is "uno"
3) a [phrase|frase] whith length [one|[uno|one]], which is "[uno|one]"
```

I see two problems here:

- The word `phrase` is being replaced instead of `a phrase`. I think that this can be fixed by sorting the dictionary by length, giving priority to longer terms.
- The already replaced words are being re-replaced, like `uno` in `[one|uno]`. I thought of using some sort of regular expression list (with [`Regex::union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union)), but I don't know how efficient and clean it'll be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your second problem, you have to replace in a single pass.

Convert the dictionary into a hash with the key-value pairs in the order you mention (sorted by length, perhaps).

```
dictionary = {
  "a phrase" => "[a phrase|una frase]",
  "phrase" => "[phrase|frase]",
  "one" => "[one|uno]",
  "uno" => "[uno|one]",
}
```

Then replace all in a single pass.

```
text.gsub(Regexp.union(*dictionary.keys.map{|w| "\b#{w}\b"}), dictionary)
```

Comment: I though of this solution, and I'm gratefull that you posted a snippet. However, I don't know how efficient `Regex::union` are. Maybe I'll do a benchmark later to test it out for a thousand terms on the dictionary, on a 2k words length file. Thank you!

Comment: If you can restrict the pattern, for example like `/\b\w+ ?\w+/`, then you do not need to use `Regexp.union`.

Comment: Terms may have an undefined amount of words. I can't simplify the regular expression that way.

Comment: Then using `union` cannot be avoided, probably. And I think that would be faster than iterating over each individual dictionary entry because `union` will short-curcuit trying the alternatives at each match point, one a match is found.

Comment: Wikiti's original solution will traverse the dictionary once and traverse the text the same number of times as there are keys in the dictionary. sawa's solution will traverse the dictionary once and traverse the text once too. The tricky part is compiling the unioned regular expressions, which I think will take less time than traversing the text many times.